# SwiftUI DragGesture only in one direction

Tags: swiftui

I'd like SwiftUI DragGesture to start only when the gesture is in a specific direction (horizontal/vertical). Is it possible?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes, it is, by applying one of the two components (either horizontal or vertical) of the gesture translation to the view offset.

Here's such behaviour implemented as a `ViewModifier`.

```swift
struct DraggableModifier : ViewModifier {

    enum Direction {
        case vertical
        case horizontal
    }

    let direction: Direction

    @State private var draggedOffset: CGSize = .zero

    func body(content: Content) -> some View {
        content
        .offset(
            CGSize(width: direction == .vertical ? 0 : draggedOffset.width,
                   height: direction == .horizontal ? 0 : draggedOffset.height)
        )
        .gesture(
            DragGesture()
            .onChanged { value in
                self.draggedOffset = value.translation
            }
            .onEnded { value in
                self.draggedOffset = .zero
            }
        )
    }

}
```

**Demo:**

```swift
struct ContentView: View {

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Spacer(minLength: 100)
            HStack {
                Rectangle()
                    .foregroundColor(.green)
                    .frame(width: 100, height: 100)
                    .modifier(DraggableModifier(direction: .vertical))
                Text("Vertical")
            }
            Spacer(minLength: 100)
            Rectangle()
                .foregroundColor(.red)
                .frame(width: 100, height: 100)
                .modifier(DraggableModifier(direction: .horizontal))
            Text(verbatim: "Horizontal")
            Spacer(minLength: 100)
        }
    }
}
```

**Result**:

[image]

Comment: Hi Matteo. Thank you for your answer but it's not exactly what I was looking for. I wanted the gesture to **start** recognizing only in a specific direction. A typical UIKit implementation would use `gestureRecognizerShouldBegin` and return `false` if the direction was wrong. Your solution always starts recognizing and only applies the offset in the specific axis.

Comment: I'm sorry if it looks like I'm not considerate of other people's time, that's definitely not something I do. I appreciated Matteo's answer a lot but I thought the question was clear enough. I asked about "SwiftUI DragGesture to **start** only when the gesture is in a specific direction".

Now, after some time has passed, I agree the question could be formulated better. I'm gonna accept the answer. Thanks for pointing that out Punkbit.

Answer (score 8):

Rather old question but didn't find the answer elsewhere.

You can easily check wether it was a left- or a right-swipe, because Gestures return their end state, which contains the starting and final position.

```swift
Text("Hello")
    .gesture(
        DragGesture(minimumDistance: 100)
            .onEnded { endedGesture in
                if (endedGesture.location.x - endedGesture.startLocation.x) > 0 {
                    print("Right")
                } else {
                    print("Left")
                }
            }
```

Comment: Thanks this helped!

Comment: missing ")" in the end (from ".gesture()" )

Comment: With this implementation, you can start dragging you can start dragging to the expected direction and then dragging it back towards the initial position – something to keep in mind.

Comment: Sorry, this doesn't have anything to do with the question.

Answer (score 1):

This will only move the view if the gesture moves move horizontally than vertically. The isDragging boolean makes sure after the first condition is met, the view will move vertically too. It's not necessary, but it helps for smoother dragging.

```
@State var dragOffset: CGSize = .zero
@State var isDragging = false

.offset(x: offset.width, y: offset.height)
        .gesture(DragGesture()
                    .onChanged { if abs($0.translation.width) > abs($0.translation.height) || isDragging {
                        self.offset = $0.translation
                        self.isDragging = true
                        
                    }
                    }
                    .onEnded {
                        isDragging = false
                        
                    })
```

Answer (score 1):

An example in which, at the start of the movement, a vertical or horizontal movement is determined after which the object moves only in this direction

```
struct Test: View {

    @State private var offsetX = CGFloat.zero
    @State private var offsetY = CGFloat.zero
    
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            Divider()
            Divider().rotationEffect(.degrees(90))
            Divider().rotationEffect(.degrees(45))
            Divider().rotationEffect(.degrees(-45))

            VStack {
                Spacer()
                Text("offsetX: \(offsetX)     offsetY: \(offsetY)")
                    .foregroundColor(.black.opacity(0.5))
                    .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
                    .padding(.bottom, 18.0)
            }
            
            Rectangle()
                .fill(.green)
                .frame(width: 300.0, height: 200.0)
                .cornerRadius(13.0)
                .offset(x: offsetX, y: offsetY)
                .gesture(drag)
        }
    }
    
    @State private var horizontal = true
    @State private var vertical = true
    
    var drag: some Gesture {
        DragGesture()
            .onChanged { dg in
                var x = dg.translation.width
                var y = dg.translation.height
                
                if ((x < 0 && y < 0 && x < y) || (x < 0 && y > 0 && -x > y) || (x > 0 && y < 0 && x > -y) || (x > 0 && y > 0 && x > y)) && self.horizontal && self.vertical {
                    self.horizontal = true
                    self.vertical = false
                } else if vertical && horizontal {
                    self.horizontal = false
                    self.vertical = true
                }
                
                if self.horizontal {
                    self.offsetX = x
                } else {
                    self.offsetY = y
                }
            }
            .onEnded { _ in
                withAnimation {
                    self.offsetX = .zero
                    self.offsetY = .zero
                }
                self.horizontal = true
                self.vertical = true
            }
        
    }
}
```

**Demo:** https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vdbkx.gif

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: I disagree, the answer is clear and the code can easily be tested.